# Goroutines on Individual servers

Tags: go, goroutine

I am working on an application in Go in which I am using goroutines. Each of which connects to third party servers and collects data which is then processed and used in application.

Just as an example :

```
for _, apiInfo := range apiInfoList {
    go external1.GetResponse(searchReq)
    go external2.GetResponse(searchReq)
    go external3.GetResponse(searchReq)
}
```

Now these goroutines are running on single server.

Is it possible to run goroutines on individual servers. ?
In my case can I run it on three different servers?

Comment: You could run a copy of your app on each server. But this is opening a big can of worms.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? At some point the data is aggregated in one place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A goroutine (it's a single word) by its very definition is a light-weight [thread of execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) *inside a single [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))* managed by an [operating system's kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)).

Hence the question as stated has no sense: if you want a task to be carried out by a separate *process* you do not need a goroutine — you need a separate process (no matter whether it is to be run on the same machine or not).

To exchange data between separate processes, you need to use some form of [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).